# react rendering list items

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs

Can someone please help me with the below code? Component is working fine but it's not rendering list items, I am unable to find a way to return the list items in render function

```
import React from 'react'
import PageLinks from './PageLinks'

const PaginationSection = React.createClass({

onClickHandle (pageNumber) {
 this.props.pageNumberClicked(pageNumber)
},

   renderPageNumbers () {
    let page = 1;
    console.log('inside render');
    while (page < this.props.totalPages) {
      console.log(this.props.totalPages);
      console.log(page);
      if (page == this.props.currentPage) {
        <li key={page}><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
      }
      else {
        <li key={page}><PageLinks pageNumber={page} onPageClick={this.onClickHandle} /></li>
      }
      page++;
    }
  },

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.props.totalPages > 1 
          ? <ul className="pagination">
              {this.renderPageNumbers()}
            </ul>
         : <div>&nbsp;</div> 
        }
      </div>   
  )}
})

export default PaginationSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return array of elements from `renderPageNumbers` method, e.g.:

```
renderPageNumbers () {
  let page = 1;
  const pages = [];
  while (page < this.props.totalPages) {
    if (page == this.props.currentPage) {
      pages.push(<li key={page}><span>&nbsp;</span></li>);
    }
    else {
      pages.push(<li key={page}><PageLinks pageNumber={page} onPageClick={this.onClickHandle} /></li>);
    }
    page++;
  }
   return pages;
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @madox2. It worked. you're a life saver ..:):)